# Opencv Datatype definition

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, types

I wanted to access my pixels in opencv 2 in some smart way. For that I defined the following pixel structure:

```
struct mypixels
{
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
};
```

now I have tried the following and it works:

```
int sz[3] = {2,2};
cv::Mat XL(2,sz, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar::all(0));
cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> pixiter = XL;
pixiter.at<mypixels>(0,0).green = 22;
```

Now this code works well in release mode but in debug mode I get an access violation error. I didn't want to hack or rewrite the opencv classes. I just want to understand what I should do to let this code work in release and debug mode.
I thought maybe I should define my pixels like the way it is written here:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#datatype
But I could not understand how or what I should do here.
Maybe here is someone who knows more.

--EDIT--

With the working solution of user2151446 and some additional brain power i came to this solution:

```
template<> class cv::DataType<mypixels>
{
public:
    typedef mypixels value_type;
    typedef int work_type;
    typedef unsigned char channel_type;
    typedef value_type vec_type;
    enum { depth = CV_8U, channels = 3,
           type = CV_MAKETYPE(depth, channels), fmt=(int)'u' };
};
```

Comment: int sz[3] = {2,2}; 3 member array is initialized with just two values. Is that what you really want?

Comment: this is a mistake I wannted only two dimensions but I think this should make no differences in the code

Comment: Really? This would make the cv_Mat to allocate memory for an additional dimension of undefined size.

Comment: I use the following constructor for the object     Mat(int ndims, const int* sizes, int type, const Scalar& s); the first value tells the constructor where there is data in the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code "works" in release mode is that the following assertion is disabled:

```
template<typename _Tp> inline _Tp& Mat::at(int i0, int i1)
{
    CV_DbgAssert( dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] &&
        (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels()) &&
        CV_ELEM_SIZE1(DataType<_Tp>::depth) == elemSize1());
    return ((_Tp*)(data + step.p[0]*i0))[i1];
}
```

You can add this after the definition of mypixels (although I am not sure I recommend it):

```
template<> class DataType<mypixels>
{
public:
    typedef mypixels value_type;
    typedef int work_type;
    typedef value_type channel_type;
    typedef value_type vec_type;
    enum { depth = 1, channels = 3,
           type = CV_MAKETYPE(depth, channels) };
};
```

And then you can do this:

```
Mat_<mypixels>& M1 = (Mat_<mypixels>&)pixiter;
M1.at<mypixels>(0,0).green = 22;
```

Comment: Hi thanks this works :) I also don t know if this makes sense .... but sometimes you need your own pixel definition. Thanks a lot again for taking your time for this

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `cv::Vec3b` type as template parameter in `pixiter.at<T>(row,col)`.
Since your custom type corresponds to the definition of `cv::Vec3b` oyu can directly cast the result if you need.

Oh, by the way, OpenCV's default color ordering is BGR.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two problems.

1. Ensure that you are using the right release mode binaries for running the program.
2. Your usage of the iterator templated with mypixels for a matrix which contains elements of type cv::Vec3b is not correct. Eventhough they are similarly defined types, they cannot be assumed to be the same.

The cleanest way is

```
int sz[3] = {2,2};
cv::Mat XL(2,sz, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar::all(0));
cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> pixiter = XL;
pixiter.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,0).val[1] = 22;
```

If you really want to do in your way, you could do something like this. But this will break when OpenCV change their data structure, if by chance.

```
int sz[3] = {2,2};
cv::Mat XL(2,sz, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar::all(0));
cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> pixiter = XL;
cv::Vec3b& aVec = pixiter.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,0);
mypixels& aMyPixel = reinterpret_cast<mypixels&>(aVec);
aMyPixel.green = 22;
```